# JQuery Wildcard for using atttributes in selectors

Tags: jquery-selectors, wildcard, jquery-attributes

I've research this topic extensibly and I'm asking as a last resort before assuming that there is no wildcard for what I want to do.

I need to pull up all the text input elements from the document and add it to an array. However, I only want to add the input elements that have an id.

I know you can use the \S* wildcard when using an id selector such as $(#\S*), however I can't use this because I need to filter the results by text type only as well, so I searching by attribute.

I currently have this:

```
values_inputs = $("input[type='text'][id^='a']");
```

This works how I want it to but it brings back only the text input elements that start with an 'a'. I want to get all the text input elements with an 'id' of anything.
I can't use:

```
values_inputs = $("input[type='text'][id^='']"); //or
values_inputs = $("input[type='text'][id^='*']"); //or
values_inputs = $("input[type='text'][id^='\\S*']"); //or
values_inputs = $("input[type='text'][id^=\\S*]"); 
//I either get no values returned  or a syntax error for these
```

I guess I'm just looking for the equivalent of * in SQL for JQuery attribute selectors.
Is there no such thing, or am I just approaching this problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's quite simple:

```
var values_inputs = $("input[type=text][id]");
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! You're right. I can't believe it's so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is a bit ambiguous. I believe you *don't* want elements with *any* id, but rather elements where id does *not* equal an empty string. Use this.

```
values_inputs = $("input[type='text']")
    .filter(function() { 
        return this.id != '';
     });
```

Comment: actually, I'm mending someone else's html code. So none of the form elements have id's. I just need to add id's to the ones I need to use. I need to filter out all other random input elements floating around randomly in the rest of the document. So I guess it is easier to just add elements with id's, which will have a value since I'm coding it in and using them later on in my function.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your selector to:

```
$("input[type='text'][id]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another way to use wild cards very simply. This helped me a lot so I thought I'd share it.

You can use attribute wildcards in the selectors in the following way to emulate the use of '*'. Let's say you have dynamically generated form in which elements are created with the same naming convention except for dynamically changing digits representing the index:

```
id='part_x_name' //where x represents a digit
```

If you want to retrieve only the text input ones that have certain parts of the id name and element type you can do the following:

```
var inputs = $("input[type='text'][id^='part_'][id$='_name']");
```

and voila, it will retrieve all the text input elements that have "part_" in the beginning of the id string and "_name" at the end of the string. If you have something like

```
id='part_x_name_y' // again x and y representing digits
```

you could do:

```
var inputs = $("input[type='text'][id^='part_'][id*='_name_']"); //the *= operator means that it will retrieve this part of the string from anywhere where it appears in the string.
```

Depending on what the names of other id's are it may start to get a little trickier if other element id's have similar naming conventions in your document. You may have to get a little more creative in specifying your wildcards. In most common cases this will be enough to get what you need.